# How to pass object as a param on ngModelChange angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

Notice: Im just starting with angular..
Ok, this is what I have:

```
<select class="form-control custom-select"
      [(ngModel)]=package
      (ngModelChange)="bindPackageCount(package)"
      formControlName="packagingProfile">
       <option *ngFor="let package of createdPackageData"
               [value]="package.count">
               {{package.package.name}} - {{package.type.name}}
       </option>
 </select>
```

By providing package.count as [value] of a select tag I can bind to it and pass it as param to bindPackageCount. What Im trying to do is to pass complete package (object) as a param not just the package.count (number). However, when I do that

```
bindPackageCount(package) {
    // package resolves to [Object object]
}
```

Per questions from others.. Yes, this is a reactive form, here is its creation:

```
createPackagingForm() {
    this.packagingForm = this._fb.group({
        packagingProfile: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

any ideas? thx

Comment: Is this a reactive form? If so, provide the form and the creation of the form :)

Comment: Any specific reason to use `ngModel`?

Comment: @developer033 reason for using ngModel is because I thought that is the way how I get the [value] from select.. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a reactive form, there is no need to use `ngModel` or `ngModelChange`. The changes will be caught with the `formControlName`. From what I understand, you want to bind the whole `package` object to your form, that can be achieved by using `[ngValue]`, which in contrary to `[value]` binds the whole object. So your select would look like this:

```
<select formControlName="packagingProfile">
   <option *ngFor="let package of createdPackageData" [ngValue]="package">
           {{package.name}} - {{package.type}}
   </option>
</select>
```

With that, you have the whole object stored in your formcontrol `packagingProfile`

### <strike>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qcv6l3G18OhMtPpemlqN?p=previewhttp://)</strike>

NB, Broken link

Comment: You are welcome! Did it solve your issue? in that case consider accepting the answer :) Furthermore, have a great day and happy coding! :)

Comment: You do not answer the question, he's not asking about reactive or not reactive.

Comment: @miguelk5 I disagree, I tell OP to use `ngValue` instead of `value`. With this being a form, I advice not to mix these form types. Back when I answered this question, this was not recommended but didn't throw an error/warning. Luckily something has been done to this, since people misused it way too much ;) https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event of option and get package value like this

```
<select class="form-control custom-select"
      [(ngModel)]=package
      formControlName="packagingProfile">
       <option *ngFor="let package of createdPackageData"
               [value]="package.count" (click)="bindPackageCount(package)">
               {{package.package.name}} - {{package.type.name}}
       </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: ..not quite what I needed, but I appreciate the effort. Im trying to pass let package as a param for bindPackageCount, not just the package.count